# Swift 3: Transfer Utility, how to retry upload after failure?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

This is how my completionHandler looks like:

```
self.completionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            if ((error) != nil){

                //retry upload
            }

            else{

                //success
            }
        })

    }
```

I don't see any method I can call on `task` to retry it, I only see `continue` method, but not sure how to use it.

I start upload for the first time the following way:

```
transferUtility.uploadData(
        data as Data,
        bucket: "test",
        key: "testTU3/try\(Date()).jpeg",
        contentType: "image/jpeg",
        expression: expression,
        completionHander: completionHandler).continue(successBlock: { (task) -> AnyObject! in
            if let error = task.error {
                NSLog("Error: %@",error.localizedDescription);

            }
            if let exception = task.exception {
                NSLog("Exception: %@",exception.description);

            }
            if let _ = task.result {

                NSLog("Upload Starting!")
                // Do something with uploadTask.
            }

            return nil;
        })
```

How to retry upload in completionHandler after failure?

**EDIT:**

here is what I've tried

```
 self.completionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            if ((error) != nil){
                guard let data = task.request?.httpBody else {return}
                self.uploadData(data: data as NSData, bucket: task.bucket, key: task.key)

            }

            else{
            }
        })
    }
```

But the problem is that I can't get the actual data of the request since

`task.request?.httpBody` evaluates to nil.

Is such approach a good idea? I know it might lead to endless running loop

Answer (score 0):

Transfer Utility does not support retries you will have to make the call yourself after failure.

In regards to your code. If you call the `continue(successBlock:)` method, the code inside the block will only execute if the upload was successful. There is another variation `continue(block:)` which will execute even when there is an error.

Comment: what data are you expecting to get?

Comment: I thought it's going to be the data I sent in that request before, in my case this image

Comment: I don't think the data will be set in the request you get back. That could potentially be rather large.

Comment: So, is there any way to extract this data from task?

Comment: You want access to the data that you passed into the method?

Comment: yes, indeed, the data that represents the image so I can upload them once more from the completion handler in case of failure

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to get that information back. If you use `continue(block:)`, then you could use the local reference to the data to create another upload request.

Comment: If I have multiple requests, I have to distinguish which one failed, so to identify them by task would be important. Still I think it's better to set flags when transfer fails and retry maybe elsewhere in app life-cycle methods :)

Comment: Then you would probably have to maintain your own record of the uploads and persist the data in a file.